# How to create zipped file using C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, zip

I want to create a C++ application in Visual Studio which reads paths of multiple files and zips them into a file. Is there a way to achieve this using C++ like we have ZipFile and Directory system support in .Net/C#?

Comment: There are libraries for this. Although you may want to do what I do instead of linking with a library just spawn 7zip passing it the correct command line parameters and have it to the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should go through zlib manual which you can use on Windows. You can find manual at https://zlib.net/manual.html

Comment: Minizip builds upon zlib to offer pkzip file format support btw.

Answer (score 0):

Standard C++ has nothing to do with Zip archive. Unfortunately, there's no easy way to take care of Zip format. You should find your way.

I recommend using [libarchive](https://www.libarchive.org/) which is an open source C library that can handle many kind of compression formats like zip, 7-zip or gzip.

`minizip` which is a contributed module include in `zlib` is also a good option. It is very tiny, simple and easy to use and works fine. I used to use it until I moved to write code with `libarchive`.